# How to show the same font which in photoshop on my webpage?

Tags: html, css, fonts, photoshop

I have a text in photoshop with font: "Arial 17 **pt** regular strong" how can I write it in css to show the same?

My 2 problems are:
1- the pt unit in photoshop, what is it in css?
2- if the font is bold strong in photoshop, how it will look like in css?

[image]

Comment: "Pt" in your photoshop application can be very different from "Pt" as defined on the web. The best solution would be @David Thomas' changing 17px to 17pt (which won't be right) and adjusting it until it's as close to what you're looking for as possible.

Comment: A `pt` is 1/72 of an inch. Accurately rendering it depends on the visitor's browser being calibrated so it knows how many pixels are in an inch for the particular screen being used. This is rare. Using absolute units also ignores user preferences and causes accessibility problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    .someclass{
     font: bold 17px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    }
```

And if you need to change the color:

```
.someclass{
     font: bold 17px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
     color: #333;
    }
```

Comment: Sorry, but I gotta give it to @David you have used a shorthand as oppose to self explanatory attributes as David has, shorthands should be used once the attributes are understood properly and the user has a better understand of css.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming it's for a paragraph (but if not, just change the selector):

```
p {
  font-family: Arial;
  font-style: normal; /* as opposed to 'italic' or 'oblique' */
  font-weight: bold; /* or 700, or 900 */
  font-size: 17px; /* consider using relative sizing, for example with 'em' units */
  line-height: 20px; /* or as appropriate */
}
```

As @Joel notes, in the comments, there is a (potentially vast) difference between `pt` and `px`. It's worth noting also that `pt` is more applicable to the print, rather than screen 'digital' medium.

Comment: The difference between px and pt may be substantial. It might require OP clarification on which unit to use.

Comment: @Joel: a good point, I hadn't noticed it was `pt`, I totally misread it as `px` (+1).

Answer (score 1):

u can change "**PT"**unit to **px** unit in Photoshop and then work,
go to

> Edit > Preferences > Units & Rulers > units > Type >select Pixels

Hope it will work for you....

& for css use "strong" with  your given text